# Android androidTestCompile espresso-core causing FileNotFoundException R.txt

Tags: android, android-espresso, r.java-file

I'm trying to add

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

To my gradle file but I get a error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processProdDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/pstafford/workspace/mobile-android-ladenzeile/app/build/intermediates/symbols/androidTest/prod/debug/R.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Any ideas?

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:1.15.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'

    testCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.11'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:1.6.6'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.6'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.2.2"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0"




    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


}
```

I've to add some lines of comments because there are too many lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

  Use this please ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I still have the same problem though. I'll upload the full gradle on the question.